# Помогите решить задачу. Циклы C#

Tags: c#, циклы

24. Сдвинуть циклически значения разрядов целого числа на заданное число позиций в заданном направлении. Например, сдвиг на две позиции влево:
    Исходное число:     123456
    Результат:          345612

Получается только такая конкретная программа.

```
int x;
int y;
int z;
Console.WriteLine("Введите число");
x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
while (x>0)
{
    y = x % 10000;
    z = x / 10000;

    Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", y, z);
    break;
}
```

А нужно, чтобы при введении конкретного числа, число сдвигалось на введенную позицию, то есть это не обязательно на две позиции влево. Например, человек может ввести значение 3, и число должно сдвинуться на три позиции влево.

Comment: И что у вас не получается?

Comment: Подсказка #1: Переведите число в массив цифр, массив проще сдвигать. Подсказка #2: Деление на 10, остаток от деления на 10 и кол-во цифр в числе.

Comment: Ну, тогда через деления степени 10 и соответствующих остатков от деления. 10^1 = 10, 10^2 = 100 и т.д., надеюсь намек поняли как решать?

Comment: если на 10, то это уже получается сдвиг не на две позиции

Comment: А что эта конкретная программа делает?

Comment: Вводится число, например, 123456. Выводится 345612.

Comment: @Maria Ага! Значит Вы можете написать функцию, которая сдвинет цифры на одну позицию вправо или влево?

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы цифры сдвигались на такое кол-во позиций влево, которое введет через консоль человек

Comment: @Maria Вы можете написать функцию, которая сдвинет цифры на одну позицию вправо (или влево)?

Comment: Да, могу))))))) столько скобочек для длины:)

Comment: @Maria Отлично. Сделайте так, чтобы эта функция возвращала сдвинутое число (если хотите - в виде строки). И вызывайте эту функцию столько раз, на сколько позиций надо сдвинуть.

Comment: "И вызывайте эту функцию столько раз, на сколько позиций надо сдвинуть." именно это у меня и не получается сделать. я совсем еще зеленая в этом всем.

Comment: Кажется, поняла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Console.WriteLine("Введите число");
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Введите сдвиг");
    int s = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int t = x;
    int m = 1;
    int n = 1;
    while (t > 0) {
       if (s > 0)
         m *= 10;
       else
         n *= 10;
       t /= 10;
       s--;
    }
    t = (x % n) * m + (x / n);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", t);
```

Comment: for (int i = 0; i<x;i++) ? Я извиняюсь, у нас только началось программирование, еще и удаленно))) Можно, пожалуйста, подробнее расписать?

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!!! Все работает, теперь пошла разбираться)